# Wordpress - Mass uncheck secondary category(ies) in all posts

Tags: wordpress

I got 600 products and did bulk edit - price change successfully. Additionally I noticed that it added all categories to all products. So every product is available through all 4 categories.

Is there a way to keep the primary category only by mass editing it? It is a huge job to edit every post and to uncheck "secondary" categories.

Comment: so you want to remove second category from all 600 products???

Comment: Do you have access to the database?

Comment: Yes I want to remove 3 from total 4 categories from every post.

Yes I have access to the database and everything else.